# Will installing 12.04 delete contents on a hard drive?

Tags: installation, hard-drive

Back story: I just built a new computer about a month and installed an SSD and an HDD. Today my SSD (OCZ Vertex 4) died on me resulting in a loss of my Windows 7 OS. Being a Ubuntu user on another pc, I want to install ubuntu on my HDD.

My question comes as I would like to know if installing ubuntu on the HDD will erase the contents of the HDD? I have done installs along side Windows before, but in this situation there is no operating system on this HDD, just program files and the like. I'm using a live CD of 12.04 currently. I just want to make sure that I don't lose any more of my files before proceeding.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Best wishes

Comment: can't you just create a partition on the HDD and install ubuntu on that one partition?

Comment: To clarify, I guess I am asking is if I go through the ubuntu partition portion of the installer and confine it to a certain amount of memory, will the original files remain on the HDD? 
Or will I have to use gparted or similar to create a partition then install onto that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a new install instead of an upgrade to an old version you need to have a dedicated partition for the new system. The old data in that partitioning will be overwritten in the system install process. If you don't have an available partition make it with gparted from unused disk area. If you don't have unused disk area you may get it by resizing some of your old partitions.